# Laptop Battery Percentage Suddenly Drops

Tags: battery, thinkpad, 17.04

On Ubuntu 17.04, the laptop battery percentage suddenly drops from 40% or 60% to 6%. The laptop is relatively new, being only 8 months old. This percentage drop  occur in windows too.

My laptop is : Lenovo Thinkpad E550

How to Fix This ?

Please Help Me

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My Question is : how to fix this ? David Forester

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for Lenovo ThinkPads, definitely recalibrate.  I had a brand new batter that did the same thing and it just needed to be recalibrated to reset the internal saved full/empty state.

The tlp utility will do this for you.  E.g.

```
    sudo tlp recalibrate BAT0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your battery is defect, replace it (under warranty if possible).

Comment: Thanks for your help , but is n`t there any fix for this  , because i`m not having any time to go to the shop and replace the battery , i heard that i can do re-calibration to the battery would fix this , is this gonna fix the problem in your opinion ?

Comment: Definitely not. Part of the battery's cells are defect, that causes the jump in charge percentage. You either live with it or replace the battery.

Comment: but i noticed a weird thing , before this issue occurs the laptop battery was lasting for about 3 hours now it takes 3 hours to get to 50 % or 60% and then drops to 6%